# IE11 does not escape a concatenated "<" character

Tags: html, internet-explorer, character-encoding, special-characters

I have a string, say `hello <whatever>, how are you?`. When I check the "page source", I get proper rendering of that string (with special characters converted).

However, if I try to read that string and put it on a pop-up window message, the message will read `hello , how are you?`. If I place a space after the `<` character (i.e.: `hello < whatever >, how are you?`), the pop-up message displays correctly: `hello < whatever >, how are you?`.

How can I properly escape the `<` character so that the entire text gets read properly? `&lt;` and `&064;` does not do the trick (remember that they are properly converted anyway).

Summary: any string that has a `<` special character followed by any alphabetical character without any blank space in between cannot be properly read by IE(11).

Edit: As soon as I posted this question, you can see what I mean by reading the first sentence. It shows as `hello , how are you?` even though I typed `hello < whatever>, how are you?` with no space between the `<` character and `whatever`.

Comment: Because I edited your question your last comment is not valid any more.

Comment: Why do you think that you can't/shouldn't  use `&lt;` or `&064;`? That the `<` is correctly displayed in the sourcecode is because the sourcecode is shown to you as plain text where the code is not interpreted. `<whatever>` is a html tag with the name `whatever`  and as of that won't be visible when rendered. Beside that `&lt;whatever&gt;` will be correctly shown as  `<whatever>`   when rendered.

Comment: The construct "< whatever" results in *invalid* HTML markup. Since the browser *cannot* interpret it as an element start - due to the space; this has naught to do with the closing brace - it "does the next best thing" and displays it as text. (Chrome and IE both work like this; I'm not sure how this *invalid* markup is officially ruled in w3c specs.)

Comment: What do you mean with  `if I type [...] in rendered HTML`? When/where do you type in rendered HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use HTML character encoding:

```
&lt; for <

&gt; for >
```

See the [W3C's Character Entity Reference Chart](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) for more information.

Comment: No need to escape the `>` in most contexts. The `<` doesn't (and shouldn't) be escaped in CDATA sections like SCRIPT elements.