# IE(11) does not escape "<" character when concatenated with an alphabetical character

Tags: html, internet-explorer, special-characters

I posted a similar question earlier but all replies missed the point or just assumed something basic/simple, so I'll try to explain again. Please read on if you wish to help...

I want to be able to type `something like <this> is visible` and have it show up on a rendered page. When I type the same text without this site's `code-text`, this is what I get: "something like  is visible". Notice that the text between the "<" and ">" is missing.

In fact, I had to add the ">" character otherwise this text would have never showed up. This issue does not happen if the "<" character is not concatenated (i.e.: "something like < this> is visible")

The reason for that is that IE believes I am creating a tag. I want to escape the "<" special character.

Conversion does not work (i.e.: converting "<" to `&lt;` or `&#60;`).

Thank you.

Comment: Exact same behavior observed using Chrome -- not an IE-specific phenomenon. The usual solution, of course, is to surround your "exact" text with angled brackets with `<code>` or `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the character after `&lt;`? For example, to write `<A`, you could write `&lt;&#0065;`. See [this page](http://la.remifa.so/unicode/unicode.php?start=0000&end=007F) for reference.

Comment: Opening the same question again isn't great  especially if you don't reference it ([IE11 does not escape a concatenated "<" character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908379/ie11-does-not-escape-a-concatenated-character)). It does not help to clarify your actual problem.

Comment: `[...]that is that IE believes I am creating a tag[...]` well thats how html works. `<tag>`    `&lt;not-a-tag>` . A  `<`  that is not part of a tag is invalid HTML and it is just goodwill of the browser that it displays it as `<`.   `[...]Conversion does not work[...]`  again why?

Answer (score 0):

I can't insert examples into my comment, but have you tried the following:

```html
Something like &lt;&#0116;his> is visible.
```

You can [use this page as a reference](http://la.remifa.so/unicode/unicode.php?start=0000&end=007F).

Comment: Awesome, that works. However that will make things very complicated. I have to make up a table of all possible characters with their matching converted code. Is there something simpler?

Comment: @ThunderSoul It would help to know a bit more of what you're trying to do, so that I could understand what the limitations are. I don't know if you're hard-coding this, what server-side code you're using, etc., but all of that information can help me help you.

Comment: `&amp;lt;` doesn't do anything. It'll literally show &lt;

Comment: What I'm trying to do is simple. I want something like `<x` to render to page.

Well, a bit more info: I'm using JSTL c:out tag to render to page.

Comment: It would be nice to have some Java code that converts `<x` to `<'html_entity_code'` :)

Comment: For Java, [see this page](http://shankarpshetty.blogspot.com/2009/11/java-function-to-convert-string-to-html.html).

Comment: While this might _solve_ the problem it will still be invalid HTML if the `<` remains in the source code. If `&lt;` is in the source like in your example then  escaping the letter after the `&lt;` is not necessary. This will just be a hack but not a good solution as the original problem still remains (also to @ThunderSoul)